# this 強くあるために meaning

Tags: grammar, words

I found 強くあるために in this song http://www.kasi-time.com/item-21360.html and

http://j-lyric.net/artist/a00968f/l00381a.html

I'm a bit sure that it means "to be strong" Is 強くある same with 強くなる ?